# Перевести text в timestamp

Tags: php

Есть текстовый `<input name='time'>`, куда вводится что-то типа "26.05.2017".
Нужно сохранить его как `timestamp`.

```
$time = $request->time;
$request->merge(['time' => strtotime($time)]);
```

А в БД сохраняется `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

```
$time = date_create($request->time);
    $request->time = $time;
```

Сохраняет `2027-05-20 17:00:00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь объектом `DateTime`:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $request->time);
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

Выведет:

```
1495811226
```

Я так понял это `Laravel`, тогда воспользуйтесь `Carbon`:

```
$date = new Carbon($request->time);
```

И можете так в базу и ложить, если надо в `unix` то можно вот так:

```
$date->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: `Call to a member function getTimestamp() on boolean`, пробую `date_create`

Comment: @Tarasovych что в переменной `$date`? Может в другом формате приходит дата, у меня всё отработало.

Comment: `dd()` показвыает в Unix timestamp, но почему-то в БД не сейвит

Comment: @Tarasovych обновил ответ

Comment: В базу обычно кладут ;-)